# Image inside Window is ugly

Tags: qt, qml

Here is a really simple QML code

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Image {
        id: image
        source: "myImage.png"
    }
}
```

The image need to show pixel perfectly. But there is like a default antialising that make the image ugly. I compared the rendering with other image reader, and there is clearly an issue there.

I tried (not at the same time first and then combining them) :

```
antialiasing: false
smooth: false
autoTransform: false
fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
fillMode: Image.Pad
```

Nothing work, the image stay blurry ugly

Maybe the Window component is doing something or the QmlEngine, I'm loading my qml like this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/ui.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is a test project : https://github.com/BlueMagma2/imageIssue

EDIT :

I've tested a few more thing since I asked the question :

The problem is present with Qbs and QMake, on Linux and Windows.

Loading the image from qrc or loading it from outside the app have the same result.

A smaller image work with no issue. so it is probably the size of the image that cause the real trouble (256 * 16064)

Comment: Try explicitly giving `width` and `height` to your `Image`, making sure they match the source png.

Comment: Tried it already, it didn't worked.

Comment: That's funny. I don't remember having such issues. Could you please provide a complete, runnable code sample on GitHub or whatever you like so that we may have a go at it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you build your project? I cannot compile it in Qt Creator. However I have compiled it by creating new Qt Quick project, adding your files and replacing default main.cpp with yours. Image looks right. Nothing is blurred.

Comment: I used Qbs, did you used QMake ? That may be the issue then ?

Comment: I tried with QMake, and still met the same issue, are you sure the image is right ? Have you compared the result in app with a classic image reader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the image is the problem (256 x 16064), in particular : the height

Testing with different heights reveal that somewhere after 8192px of height, shifting and blurry effect start to ruin the Image (sometimes the image even become black).

The only way to solve this is to cut the image in smaller part.

I did it with a QQuickImageProvider, and since this image was a tileset, I cut it for each tile (32 x 32). For other image, it might be preferable to choose a bigger size

```
class TileImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{

public:
    TileImageProvider() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image) {}

    QHash<QString, QImage> tilesetCache;

    virtual QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize& requestedSize) {
        int width = 32;
        int height = 32;
        QStringList idData = id.split("/");
        int posX = idData.at(1).toInt();
        int posY = idData.at(2).toInt();
        if (size)
            *size = QSize(width, height);
        QImage image;
        if (!tilesetCache.contains(idData.at(0))) {
            image = QImage(":/" + idData.at(0));
            tilesetCache[idData.at(0)] = image;
        } else {
            image = tilesetCache[idData.at(0)];
        }
        return image.copy(posX * width, posY * height, width, height);
    }
};
```

You will need to declare your provider to the engine :

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("tile"), new TileImageProvider);
```

And here is an example of how to load it from QML :

```
Grid {
    id: grid
    columns: 7;
    rows: 20;

    Repeater {
        model: grid.columns * grid.rows
        delegate: Image {
            id: image
            width: 32
            height: 32
            asynchronous: true
            source: "image://tile/image.png/" + posX + "/" + posY
            smooth: false
            antialiasing: false
            fillMode: Image.Pad;

            property int posX: index % grid.columns
            property int posY: (index - posX) / grid.columns
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the mipmap option if you are using QtQuick 2.5.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#mipmap-prop

It won't be pixel perfect but its much smoother than using the smooth or anti-aliase properties.

To be pixel perfect you would need to know the exact resolution, pixel density, etc or your target device.  If you can't guarantee that, you'll never be pixel perfect anyway.

Comment: I can guarantee it, and I need it to be pixel perfect. Also, I already tried mipmap and the result is exactly the same

Comment: My target device is : my screen, the pixel density has nothing to do with it since I don't resize it to a specific dpi, I want the image to appear exactly the size it is in pixel and I do have the exact pixel size in the app.

Comment: I looked at your github project and I see the image you have is VERY tall.  You don't display that all at once I'm sure.  Have you thought about using the sprite engine perhaps to break up the image into the part you want to display at a given time?  What are you using the image for?  It looks like a map, is that accurate?

Comment: Indeed, this is a tileset, each 32*32 square can be used in combination with the others to create 2D map. I use it in a flickable

Comment: Okay so back to the idea of using the sprite engine then.  I haven't personally used it so I can't say from experience, but check out this:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-effects-sprites.html.  Might help?

Comment: thank you for your help, I solve my issue with a QQuickImageProvider, see the accepted answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

I've got very similar issue with Image positioned through binding. After googling with no results I tried to add Math.round() to coordinates and it helped!

```
handle: Image {
     id: thumb
     source: "thumb.png"
     x: Math.round( parent.leftPadding + parent.availableWidth / 2 - width / 2 )
     y: Math.round( parent.topPadding + parent.visualPosition * (parent.availableHeight - height) )
}
```